# how to stop the loop method on button click in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am making a survey app I am uploading data  to server  on start button and I want that when stop button is clicked it should stop the data uploading which is in the following method.

Below is the uploading button start button.

```
-(IBAction)startSyncButtonAction{
   CereniaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (CereniaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   for (int i=0; i<[appDelegate.coffeeArray count]; i++) {

    Coffee *coffeeObj = [appDelegate.coffeeArray objectAtIndex:i];


    int mycount=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];
    NSLog(@"My Array count is %d",mycount);


        NSString*device_Id=coffeeObj.device_Id;
        NSString*R1=coffeeObj.R1;
        NSString*R2=coffeeObj.R2;
        NSString*R3=coffeeObj.R3;
        NSString*comment=coffeeObj.comment;
            NSString*update_date_time=coffeeObj.update_date_time;



    [appDelegate removeCoffee:coffeeObj];

    int mycount1=[appDelegate.coffeeArray count];


    NSLog(@"My Array After delete is %d",mycount1);


    NSLog(@"device_Id%@",device_Id);
    NSLog(@"R1%@",R1);
    NSLog(@"R2%@",R2);
    NSLog(@"R3%@",R3);
    NSLog(@"comment%@",comment);
    NSLog(@"update_date_time%@",update_date_time);

            NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"device_Id=%@&R1=%@&R2=%@&R3=%@&comment=%@&update_date_time=%@",device_Id,R1,R2,R3,comment,update_date_time];

    NSLog(post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/pfizersurvey/SyncSurveySTD.php"];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];



    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);


     }

         }

         -(IBAction)stopButtonAction{

          }
```

Comment: You're blocking the main thread with your data upload so you won't get any button actions fired during the download. You'll need to do your networking asynchronously and then find a way to cancel in flight requests.

Comment: it is in loop can not we break the loop and close the method

Comment: @any idea how to do this

Comment: No, most importantly because you block the main thread so no button actions are going to be delivered while that loop is executing.

Comment: so any idea how to solve this and do not block the mean thread while uploading the data

Answer (score 0):

The comments have pointed out the problem. You need to do the following:

- Avoid doing any heavy work on the main thread - it will lock up the app.
- After heavy work has completed - be sure to update the UI back on the main thread. Otherwise it will be slow to synchronize.

To solve consider one of the following:

***1. Use Grand Central Dispatch:***

Grand central dispatch makes it easy to write threaded applications without having to deal directly with threads. Do the following:

```
dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(taskQ, ^
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/pah_brd_v1/pfizersurvey/SyncSurveySTD.php"];
   NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//Now update back on the main thread
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
    //Now update the view with your data, to show the outcome of the POST
});
    });

dispatch_release(taskQ);
```

***2. Use a network library, that does this for you.***

- AFNetworking is very popular
- I like LRResty which is just a thin layer of NSURLConnection - does essentially what I wrote above, and a minimal bunch of other things.

***3. Use [NSURLConnection +sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:];***

***4. Use an operation queue.***

***5. Use threads.***